# pines notify container

Tags: jquery

I am using [Pines Notify](http://pines.sourceforge.net/pnotify/) plugin for jquery and would like to us it while using jquery dialog that has an iframe.Currently this works except that in put the growl message inside the iframe rather than on the parent. Does anyone out there know how to apply it to the parent about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to include the plugin in the parent page (I assume jQuery already is if you have a dialog), then just reference it using [`window.parent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp), like this:

```
window.parent.$.pnotify({
  pnotify_title: 'Title',
  pnotify_text: 'Content'
});
```

This calls the plugin in the parent page/frame rather than in the `<iframe>`.  Also, this only works if the parent and `<iframe>` are on the same domain due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), hopefully this is a non-issue for you.